# Locating and extracting (unknown) book from an image in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I'm trying to locate a (possibly perspective-deformed) book in an image and extract it so that it is "straight" and "front-on" (i.e. perspective-corrected).

The particular book is unknown -- there is no query or reference image to check for matches against (i.e. by some sort of feature descriptor matching process). In other words, I'm trying to hunt through the image and find a bunch of pixels that look like they belong to the object class "book", not a particular book.

The book may be somewhat rotated or otherwise perspective-deformed. However, it is assumed the amount of deformation is within fairly reasonable bounds: the person taking the photo is working "with" me. This means as well that the book should feature prominently in the image -- perhaps 30-90% of total image area (and not as some random item amidst a bunch of other clutter).

Good resources exist for (superficially) similar problems online. For example, this well-written tutorial covers automatic perspective-correction of *playing cards*: https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/.

Currently, the system follows a loosely similar process as this tutorial, with some  additions. The general technique stack is:

1. Pre-processing
2. Find edges with Canny edge detection
3. Find edges that look like lines with Hough transform
4. Find intersection points between lines in the hope of finding book corners
5. Filter out implausible lines and intersection points based on simple geometric properties
6. Take convex hull of intersection points
7. Get polygon approximation to the convex hull and use this to get four corners
8. Apply perspective/homographic transform

The output points (used to calculate the perspective transform) are known because we assume a known aspect ratio (i.e. book dimensions).

It works for some images where the book is against fairly homogeneous backgrounds (around 1/3 to 1/2 of "nicer" images). After experimenting with the fairly dumb convex hull approach as well as a more involved quadrilateral-enumeration approach, I've concluded that the problem may be impossible using just geometric/spatial information alone -- it would probably need augmenting with colour/texture information (well, this is obvious when you consider the case of 180 degrees rotation/upside-down books).

The obvious challenge is that there is an almost infinite variety of possible book covers, and an almost infinite variety of possible backgrounds. Therefore, solving for the general case would be impossible or at least intractably hard. I knew this when I began the task. But, I hoped it would be the sort of problem that may have a solution *enough* of the time.

Other approaches I've considered looking at include OCRing the titles/text to work out orientation or possibly general position. The other approach that might conceivably be fruitful is some sort of learning-based classifier.

A related subtask I'm working on is the same goal but in a webcam video stream. This is definitely easier since I can use temporal information (i.e. position across frames). I just started this one yesterday but, after some initial progress, plateaued. A human holding the book generates background movement noise which throws off trivial approaches like frame differencing / background subtraction. Compared with the static image problem, however, I feel this is far more doable.

Sorry if that was a little long-winded. I wanted to make sure I made a sincere effort to articulate the problem(s). What do people think? Anyone have any thoughts as to how these problems might best be tackled?

Comment: Do you get better results on the "bad" images if the image is close-cropped to the comic book, so that most of the image is taken up by the comic book?

Comment: That case is generally not too bad, since if the book borders (the presence of which are vital for the algorithm) are close to the image boundaries, then there is less room for "noise" edges in the background

Comment: So, your description has identified cluttered background surrounding the book as one of the source of mis-detection of book position. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @rwong Yeah, cluttered background is definitely one source of mis-detection (particularly if the clutter is "liney")

Comment: Well, one cost-effective way of solving the clutter problem is to solve it in a humanly way (when compared to the algorithmic way.) Looking forward to a good answer. It is going to require much more than Hough.

Comment: Hint. Discard step 6 - 8. Steps 1 - 5 are known to work in cluttered scenario, as long as every of those steps use the right parameters and settings. Instead, you already know that if the book's all four edges could be found in the Hough result (no missing edges), then the correct (ground truth) quadrilateral must exist in the set of N-choose-4 combinations of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Does calculating homography with 4 lines instead of 4 points help the problem? As you probably know, if points are related as p2=Hp1, the  lines are related as l2=H<sup>-1</sup>l1. The lines on the book border should be quite prominent especially if the deformation is not large. Is you main problem selecting right lines (you did NOT actually said what's your problem was)? May be some kind of Hough-rectangle can help to find lines?

Anyway, selecting lines for homography input has an additional advantage that RANSAC homography with a constraint on aspect ratio is likely to keep right lines as inliners in the presence of numerous outliers from the background. And if those outliers sneak in they probably look like another book.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The idea of exploiting RANSAC homography to screen out outliers kind of occurred to me and seemed like it could be useful. I didn't think about the homography input in terms of lines, maybe worth thinking about. Yeah, I'd say my main problem was selecting the right lines -- the more "bad" lines (non-book-edges), the more erroneous intersection points generated.

Comment: I hope by lines you meant connected edges rather than Hough lines since the latter have to be screened for edge support before calculating their intersections. In other words, Hough lines should be processed into line segments with enough  edge support over all length of the segments (though small gaps are usually allowed). I believe Matlab has something like this in its Hough example code.